# weblogic server redirecting to url without domain

Tags: weblogic, struts

I am trying to set up a local weblogic server to test some code that is legacy and running in production. Therefore, I'm pretty certain the problem isn't with the code. This same code also runs locally in tomcat.

The first page of my application loads fine. Then, when I click the login button it sends me to http://appname/login.do  which of course doesn't load, because there is no domain.

The inital page was loaded at http://localhost:7001/appname/index.jsp

I'm new to both weblogic and struts, but I examined the form submit code and the action is /appname/login.do for both the working tomcat instance and the production code as well as my broken weblogic instance.

The listen address on my weblogic server is configured to localhost
The listen port on my weblogic server is configured to port 7001.

I'm fairly certain that I just missed something in the configuration, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've also spent a lot of time searching and am not finding much help. It's possible that I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Thanks

Comment: so when you deploy the app on Weblogic locally - and access any link after the homepage - you just lose the localhost:7001 ? Weird. Can you try accessing with 127.0.0.1:7001 and see does it lose that as well?

Comment: Does the Admin console work fine? http://localhost:7001/console/